# Nothing is drawn when using Vertex Array Objects

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I use the following code in my iOS application, which result in an empty screen:

```
void init()
{
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vaoId);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vbId);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vaoId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbId);

    glVertexAttribPointer(originalPositionPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexPositionWithColor), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(VertexPositionWithColor, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(originalPositionPos);

    glVertexAttribPointer(originalColorPos, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexPositionWithColor), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(VertexPositionWithColor, color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(originalColorPos);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void rebinData()
{
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vaoId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbId);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexPositionWithColor) * _linesVertices.size(), &_linesVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void paint()
{
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vaoId);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, (GLsizei)_linesIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &_linesIndices[0]);
}
```

If i move the glVertexAttribPointer calls to paint() and bind the vertex buffer there, everything works. I don't understand why using vertex array object does not work as expected here?

Comment: 1. You forgot to unbind VAO in paint(). But this is not the problem here.

Comment: 2. you use glDrawElements() when nothing is bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER target. You should setup your VAO accordingly, or use glDrawArrays instead.

Comment: Actually there is no problem with the glDrawElements method. The problem in the end was that i called init() too early in the flow of the application